# How to describe set expressions in ordinary language?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the proper way to describe a set in ordinary language? For example, say we have the expression: S1({{x}, {y}} : x ∈ A : y ∈ B). I assume in this case we just say that S1 is a set of ordered pairs whose first component is an element of Set A and second component is an element of Set B and is therefore the Cartesian product of AxB. But, what about S1({{x}, {x}} : x ∈ A)? Do we say S1 is a proper subset of a superset set A such that it is a set of ordered pairs whose first component is an element of Set A and second component is also an element of Set A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the proper way to describe a set in ordinary language? For example, say we have the expression: $S_1:\{(x, y) \mid x \in A , y \in B\}$. I assume in this case we just say that $S_1$ is a set of ordered pairs whose first component is an element of Set A and second component is an element of Set B and is therefore the Cartesian product of $A\times B$.

Yes.

> But, what about $S_2=\{(x,x) \mid x \in A\}$? Do we say $S_2$ is a proper subset of a superset set A such that it is a set of ordered pairs whose first component is an element of Set A and second component is also an element of Set A?

No; not quite.  $S_2$ is composed of ordered pairs whose members are both elements of set $A$, *and* are identical to each other.

Comment: Thanks! But, is S2 not a proper subset of Set A?